# Derivation of function with two variable

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I am supposed to derivate the following function with two variable :$f\left ( n,x \right )=\arctan \left ( \frac{n}{\left | n \right |+\left | x \right |} \right )$ for $\frac{\partial f\left ( x,n \right )}{\partial x}$ in point $f\left ( 0,0 \right )=0$.

So I calculate the derivation, which is equal to: $\frac{-nx}{\left ( \left ( \left | n \right |+\left | x \right | \right )^{2}+n^{2} \right )\left | x \right |}$, but then I do not know how to determine the derivation in point $\left ( 0,0 \right )$.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Are you doing the derivative on both parameters: x and n?

Comment: @Aidan I editet my answer, it is for x

Comment: You have not defined $f(0,0)$

Comment: @KaboMurphy I edited my answer, Can you look at it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition $\frac {\partial } {\partial x} f(0,0) =\lim_{x \to 0} \frac {f(0,x)-f(0,0)} x$. This is $0$ because the numerator is $0$ for all $x \neq 0$.

Comment: So my calculation is wrong? Should I use the limit, not the derivation in the way I did?

Comment: @Daniel What you are doing is wrong. In general  you cannot find the  derivative at $(0,0)$ by finding the derivative at a  general point and then taking the limit. The right  method is to just use the definition of the partial derivative.

Comment: So what I should do is: $f(x,0)=\arctan \frac{0}{\left | 0 \right |+\left | x \right |}$ so that the limit as you wrote is 0. Is that okay?

Comment: @Daniel Yes, that is what I meant.

Comment: Thank you so much